# Get an error for using a for loop alternatively on columns of a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix which has one column names and one columns values alternatively. 
I am trying to perform a lillie.test on each value columns.

what I have done so far is as follows:

```
library("nor test")
# create a data
d <- data.frame( v1 = letters[1:10], v2 = runif(10), v3 = LETTERS[1:10],v4 = rnorm(10), v5 = letters[1:10], v6 = runif(10), v7 = LETTERS[1:10], v8 = rnorm(10), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
# make the sequence 
bm = seq(4, length(d), by=2)
# make an empty matrix 
results <- matrix(0,length(d),2)
# run the loop 
for (i in 2:bm) {
  results[i] <- lillie.test(d[,i])
}
```

errors I get

```
Error in if (pvalue > 0.1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 2:bm : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In Ops.factor(x, mean(x)) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

I get a lot of error when I run my for loop but when I apply the lillie test on each column , I see no error

when i run the function on each column, I get outputs without error
for example

```
 results <- lillie.test(d[,2])
 results

#   Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test

#data:  d[, 2]
#D = 0.2996, p-value = 0.01133
```

Now I have two questions, 
**1- how to solve this problem? 
2- is there any other way to perform this test e.g. using apply or other functions?**

if i do as follows: then the results are stored in a list. however, i want to have them in a marix like

```
            v2           v4             v6             v8                         
statistic 0.2995636     0.1783198     0.1659068       0.145466                           
p.value   0.01133228    0.4898968     0.6069414       0.793838

 bm = seq(2, length(d), by=2)
 results <- sapply(d[bm], lillie.test)
 results
          v2                                               v4                                              
statistic 0.2995636                                        0.1783198                                       
p.value   0.01133228                                       0.4898968                                       
method    "Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test" "Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test"
data.name "X[[1L]]"                                        "X[[2L]]"                                       
          v6                                               v8                                              
statistic 0.1659068                                        0.145466                                        
p.value   0.6069414                                        0.793838                                        
method    "Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test" "Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test"
data.name "X[[3L]]"                                        "X[[4L]]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check this line:

```
for (i in 2:bm)
```

It seems OK, but it isn't. Let's print `bm`:

```
bm
[1] 4 6 8
```

You see, `bm` is not an integer. I suspect you'd like to concatenate 2 with bm (judging from your data.set), so you can just do this:

```
bm <- c(2, bm)
bm
[1] 2 4 6 8
```

Or, do this (and this is better):

```
bm <- seq(2, 8, 2)
```

Now you have the values you want to test. I know nothing about the libraries you are using, but let's check *your* `2:bm`

```
2:bm
[1] 2 3 4
```

You are running the test on letters (the third column contains strings!).

A quick solution to this would be:

```
bm <- seq(4, length(d), by=2) ## as you have typed
bm <- c(2, bm)
results <- sapply(d[bm], lillie.test)
```

`d[bm]` gives us a subset of our current `data.frame`, containing only the columns specified by `bm`, so `sapply` will do the test for each and every one of those columens and store its results in `results`.

**EDIT:** This is probably what you'd like

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(results), nrow=4, byrow=F))[c(1,2), ]
```

Comment: Since I can't use that library on my installation of R, please comment whether this is the result you'd expect. I'm using an equivalent but it gives me a different result for d[,2]

Comment: thanks for your comment , if I do   'bm = seq(2, length(d), by=2)' followed by 'results <- sapply(d[bm], lillie.test)' . I get the output but they stores in a list. I want to get them in a matrix so that I can copy and paste or work with them

Comment: I updated the question based on your solution , please have a look at above

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'm converting it to a data.frame and then I only keep the numbers, as your example shows.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```
bm = seq(2, length(d), by=2)
res<- lapply(d[bm], lillie.test)
m<- do.call(cbind, res)
mresults <- m[1:2,]
print(mresults)

#          v2        v4        v6        v8       
#statistic 0.1724419 0.1113228 0.2189569 0.1650759
#p.value   0.5447331 0.9777699 0.1902882 0.6148843
```